# How to require or import only necessary exports from module with webpack

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, commonjs, es6-module-loader

For example I have module with some configurations:

```js
exports.common = {
 cookieDomain: '.mydomain.dev',
 protocol: 'http',
 apiPort: 3030
}

exports.server {
 port: 8080
}
```

In another module i want to require only `config.common`object, but avoiding that the code from `config.server` hit into the client bundle. Is this possible with webpack?

Comment: This will become possible with webpack 2 (which is currently in beta), but only for the ES2015 syntax, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Not really. Don't put both things in the same module if you don't need them together.

Answer (score 2):

This is called "Tree Shaking" and [will be a part of webpack 2](https://webpack.github.io/docs/roadmap.html).
You cannot use the CommonJS syntax though, you will need to use the ES2015 module syntax:

export:

```
export const common = {
    cookieDomain: '.mydomain.dev',
    protocol: 'http',
    apiPort: 3030
};

export const server {
    port: 8080
};
```

Import:

```
import common from 'config';

common; // do something with common
// server is not included in the bundle
```

You can install the beta version using the current version number:

```
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.6
```

Alternatively, you could also have a look at [rollup.js](http://rollupjs.org/) which supports this from the get go (and produces slightly smaller bundles as well). It only supports ES2015 syntax as well though.

Comment: I installed webpack 2 but it doesn't shakes the tree. I suspect that problem is in installed presets or plugins. Below is my .babelrc
`{
    "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0", "es2015-loose", "es2015-native-modules"],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-runtime",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-class-properties"
    ],
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "retainLines": true
}`

Comment: Remove `es2015` and `es2015-loose`, otherwise your `import`s will be transpiled into `require();`s.

Comment: i can't remove es2015 because serverside on nodejs throws error SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: Using `es2015-native-modules`?

Comment: No, it accidentally got here

Comment: Are you using webpack on node.js? I'm not sure I fully understand your question. It would be best if you create a new question for your issues, as the comment section is not very useful for this. If this has answered your initial question, please accept the answer. Thank you.